# Error con tabla en java

Tags: java, jtable, jpanel

Tengo un JFrame con un Jpanel que cambio al hacer clicks en unos Jlabel, la cuestion es que en uno de ellos relleno un Jtable y cada vez que hago click en lugar de limpiar la tabla, me añade mas registros y no veo porque ni como tratar de solucionarlo.

Este es el evento que me cambia el Jpanel que tengo en el contenedor.

```
  private void jLabel7MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    myTeam mt = new myTeam(TeamID);
    //mt.modelo.setRowCount(0);
    //while (mt.modelo.getRowCount() > 0) { mt.modelo.removeRow(0); }
    mt.setSize(938,720);
    mt.setLocation(0,0);
    container.removeAll();
    container.add(mt, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    container.revalidate();
    container.repaint();
    jPanel6.setBackground(Color.white);
    oldColor=Color.white;
}
```

Y esto es la llamada de la creacion de ese JPane

```
    public myTeam(String TeamID) {
    this.modelo.addColumn("Name");
    this.modelo.addColumn("Age");
    this.modelo.addColumn("Nat");
    this.modelo.addColumn("St");
    this.modelo.addColumn("Tk");
    this.modelo.addColumn("Ps");
    this.modelo.addColumn("Sh");
    this.modelo.addColumn("Ag");
    this.modelo.addColumn("KAb");
    this.modelo.addColumn("TAb");
    this.modelo.addColumn("PAb");
    this.modelo.addColumn("SAb");
    this.modelo.addColumn("Gam");
    this.modelo.addColumn("Sub");
    this.modelo.addColumn("Min");
    this.modelo.addColumn("Mom");
    this.modelo.addColumn("Sav");
    this.modelo.addColumn("Con");
    this.modelo.addColumn("Ktk");
    this.modelo.addColumn("Kps");
    this.modelo.addColumn("Sht");
    this.modelo.addColumn("Gls");
    this.modelo.addColumn("Ass");
    this.modelo.addColumn("DP");
    this.modelo.addColumn("Inj");
    this.modelo.addColumn("Sus");
    this.modelo.addColumn("Fit");
    initComponents();
    team_ID=TeamID;
    //while (this.modelo.getRowCount() > 0) { this.modelo.removeRow(0); }
    this.jTable1.setModel(this.modelo);
    adjustColWidthByHeader(this.jTable1);
    this.jTable1.setAutoResizeMode(0);
    if (TeamID.equals("")) {TeamID="and";}
    selectTeam(TeamID);
    
    while (this.modelo.getRowCount() > 0) { this.modelo.removeRow(0); }
    for (int i=0; i<p.size();i++){
        this.modelo.addRow(((player)p.get(i)).jugadorFila());
    }
    jLabel1.setText("");
    jLabel4.setText("");
    jLabel5.setText("");
    jLabel7.setText("");
    jLabel20.setText("");
    jLabel18.setText("");
    jLabel22.setText("");
    jLabel24.setText("");
    jLabel26.setText("");
    jLabel28.setText("");
}
```

¿Alguien sabe porque me pasa o como puedo hacer para que cada vez que pulse ese Jlabel la tabla se me vacie y rellene de nuevo?

---

Entiendo que te refieres a que declare modelo cada vez que arranco el JPanel

```
modelo = new DefaultTableModel();
```

Esto es algo que tenia ya de antes y tampoco funcionaba, ahora mismo lo deje asi y sigue fallando...

```
public myTeam(String TeamID) {
    modelo = new DefaultTableModel();
    this.modelo.addColumn("Name");
    this.modelo.addColumn("Age");
    this.modelo.addColumn("Nat");
    this.modelo.addColumn("St");
    this.modelo.addColumn("Tk");
    this.modelo.addColumn("Ps");
    this.modelo.addColumn("Sh");
    this.modelo.addColumn("Ag");
    this.modelo.addColumn("KAb");
    this.modelo.addColumn("TAb");
    this.modelo.addColumn("PAb");
    this.modelo.addColumn("SAb");
    this.modelo.addColumn("Gam");
    this.modelo.addColumn("Sub");
    this.modelo.addColumn("Min");
    this.modelo.addColumn("Mom");
    this.modelo.addColumn("Sav");
    this.modelo.addColumn("Con");
    this.modelo.addColumn("Ktk");
    this.modelo.addColumn("Kps");
    this.modelo.addColumn("Sht");
    this.modelo.addColumn("Gls");
    this.modelo.addColumn("Ass");
    this.modelo.addColumn("DP");
    this.modelo.addColumn("Inj");
    this.modelo.addColumn("Sus");
    this.modelo.addColumn("Fit");
    initComponents();
    team_ID=TeamID;
    //while (this.modelo.getRowCount() > 0) { this.modelo.removeRow(0); }
    this.jTable1.setModel(this.modelo);
    adjustColWidthByHeader(this.jTable1);
    this.jTable1.setAutoResizeMode(0);
    if (TeamID.equals("")) {TeamID="and";}
    selectTeam(TeamID);
    
    while (this.modelo.getRowCount() > 0) { this.modelo.removeRow(0); }
    for (int i=0; i<p.size();i++){
        this.modelo.addRow(((player)p.get(i)).jugadorFila());
    }
    jLabel1.setText("");
    jLabel4.setText("");
    jLabel5.setText("");
    jLabel7.setText("");
    jLabel20.setText("");
    jLabel18.setText("");
    jLabel22.setText("");
    jLabel24.setText("");
    jLabel26.setText("");
    jLabel28.setText("");
}
```

Comment: Bienvenidx a SOes! Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes. Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Answer (score 0):

es difícil saber que es lo que pasa, con el código incompleto, pero vamos a intentarlo, antes una sugerencia, declara un array con los nombres de las columnas y luego las cargas al modelo con un for:

```
String nombres[] = { "s", "d", "r" };
for( int i = 0; i < nombres.length; i++ ) {
    this.modelo.addColumn( nombres[ i ] );
}
```

No es que yo sea vago para escribir, pero...

Con respecto al error, creo adivinar que el problema es que te faltan dos lineas de código en jLabel7MouseClicked, algo así como:

```
modelo = new ModeloTabla();
this.jTable1 = new JTable( modelo );
```

Si estoy en lo correcto, es la razón por la que se agregan nuevas columnas, en vez de reemplazar las antiguas.
Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: @Debu, lo edite para volver a instanciar la tabla, a ver si funciona!!!

Comment: @Debu, no contestes en el espacio de las respuestas, los "cuidadores" te van a saltar al cuello, es mejor editar la pregunta original!!

Comment: Nada, probe como comentas y nada...

Comment: @Debu, me podrías aclarar que es "nada", sigue cargando, como antes, te arroja un error?, o que?.

Comment: SIgue haciendo lo mismo, la primera vez que pulso carga bien, pero la segunda, vez que pulso, me añade los registros, en lugar de borrar lo que habia y de meterlo de nuevo

Comment: Entonces el problema es que estás instanciando otra tabla, trata de escribir el código completo de la clase, casi te aseguraría que el problema está en el uso indiscriminado de this. y proba con this.modelo = new ModeloTabla();
this.jTable1 = new JTable( modelo );

Comment: Perdón @Debu, no mire bien lo que habías hecho, la nueva instanciación, la tienes que hacer en el método jLabel7MouseClicked, no en el constructor!!!!